TIdTCPServer binding for localhost allows connections from other IP addresses
I create a binding to allow connections only for localhost:
IdTCPServer.Bindings.Clear;
IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add;
IdTCPServer.Bindings.Items[0].SetPeer('127.0.0.1', 1001);
//...
IdTCPServer.Active := true;

But clients can still connect from other IP addresses.
Am I misunderstanding how Bindings work?

Try this:
HTTPServer.Bindings.Clear;

Binding := HTTPServer.Bindings.Add;
Binding.IP := '127.0.0.1';
Binding.Port := 1001;

Note: port 1001 is in the range of well-known ports which have special restrictions on some operating systems.

The linked web article doe not provide detailed information about the specific port. You should rather provide link to Internet Assigned Number Authority - Port 1001 which provides official information about registered port numbers

Thanks.It worked.

Right way:
IdTCPServer.Bindings.Clear;
IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add;
IdTCPServer.Bindings.Items[0].SetBinding('127.0.0.1', 1001);
//...
IdTCPServer.Active := true;


FYI, Add() returns the new binding object, so you don't need to index into the collection separately: IdTCPServer.Bindings.Add.SetBinding('127.0.0.1', 1001);
